# react native save data AsyncStorage

Tags: react-native

Good day I'm using react native. I want to save the switch button to true or false, but it doesn't. When I open and close the application does not load the recorded data. Where is the problem. It does not save true or false.

```
class LoginForm extends Component {

  toggleRememberMe = value => {
  this.setState({ rememberMe: value })
    if (value === true) {
    this.rememberUser();
  } else {
    this.forgetUser();
  }
}

rememberUser = async () => {
try {
  await AsyncStorage.setItem('123123', this.state.remem);
} catch (error) {
  // Error saving data
}
};
getRememberedUser = async () => {
try {
  const username = await AsyncStorage.getItem('123123');
  if (username !== null) {
    return username;
  }
} catch (error) {
}
};
forgetUser = async () => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.removeItem('123123');
  } catch (error) {
  }
};

constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        const remem = this.getRememberedUser();
     this.state = {
      remem: remem || "", 
      rememberMe: remem ? true : false 
        }
    }
   render() {
        return (<Switch
  value={this.state.rememberMe}
  onValueChange={(value) => this.toggleRememberMe(value)}
  /><Text>Remember Me</Text>);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to getRememberedUser() in `componentDidMount`.

Right now you have an async function that you're trying to execute outside of an async context.

Something like:

```
async componentDidMount() {
  const remem = await this.getRememberedUser();
  if (remem) {
    this.setState({rememberMe: remem})
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your `rememberUser()` method is probably being called before state updates. `setState()` is an async operation. Try updating your asyncStore after `rememberMe` is set to value you are setting it to:

```
    toggleRememberMe = value => {
     this.setState({ rememberMe: value }, ()=>{
     if (value === true) {
     this.rememberUser();
    } else {
    this.forgetUser();
  }
})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-69z16?fontsize=14) for you to get a look. Basically, moved the AsyncStorage to componentDidMount and removed some things (such as using the state for setting the AsyncStorage, this is needed because setState is async and your value couldn't be the expected)

Comment: It does work. Is that all the code you have? Maybe there is something else